# Get a array of object group by two keys using loadash

Tags: javascript, arrays, count, logic, grouping

Input:

```
[
  {
    "Country": "BR",
    "New Lv1-Lv2": "#N/A"
  },
{
    "Country": "BR",
    "New Lv1-Lv2": "#N/A"
  },
  {
    "Country": "",
    "New Lv1-Lv2": "test"
}]
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "Country": "BR",
    "New Lv1-Lv2": "#N/A",
"count":2
  },
  {
    "Country": "",
    "New Lv1-Lv2": "test",
"count":1
}]
```

i have used loadhash group by but not sure how to map multiple keys please let me know how to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build an object with aggregated count.
(PS. change key according to your needs to be unique)

```js
const convert = (arr) => {
  const res = {};
  arr.forEach((obj) => {
    const key = `${obj.Country}${obj["New Lv1-Lv2"]}`;
    if (!res[key]) {
      res[key] = { ...obj, count: 0 };
    }
    res[key].count += 1;
  });
  return Object.values(res);
};

const data = [
  {
    Country: "BR",
    "New Lv1-Lv2": "#N/A",
  },
  {
    Country: "BR",
    "New Lv1-Lv2": "#N/A",
  },
  {
    Country: "",
    "New Lv1-Lv2": "test",
  },
];

console.log(convert(data));
```